# Как создать повторяющийся border для масштабируемого элемента

Tags: css, svg, градиент

**Что я хочу создать:**

1. Пунктирную границу над  каждым `li`-элементом
2. Размер точки и расстояние между ними можно изменять настройками в CSS или в изображении SVG
3. Ширина `ul` должна быть масштабируемой, так же, как и ширина границы
4. Точки не должны быть обрезаны при изменении размера области просмотра `viewport`. Это означает, что должны быть видны только полные (целые) круги

**Я не хочу, чтобы это произошло**,- (см. крайнюю точку), при изменении размера области просмотра `viewport`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу придумать способ, чтобы создать это, используя:

`repeated background image` (повторяющиеся фоновые изображения)

огромные (очень широкие) фоновые изображения

`border-image`

**Что я получил:**

Я нашел способ, но это действительно раздражает. Это работает, но я вынужден  создавать сотни (ненужных) `span` - элементов, так как я не знаю максимальную ширину элемента.

Идея очень проста: точки, которые не вписываются, скрываются - `overflow: hidden;`

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 60px;
}

ul > li div {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 2px;
}

ul > li div span {
  float: left;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </div>
    Item 1
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </div>
    Item 2
  </li>
</ul>
```

Есть ли другие хорошие способы решить эту проблему с помощью SVG, градиентов?

Источник: [How to create a repeated border for a responsive element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869325/how-to-create-a-repeated-border-for-a-responsive-element)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869325/how-to-create-a-repeated-border-for-a-responsive-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-image` выглядит как ссылка, на изображение, где оно расположено. Вы можете контролировать размер, и указать, что повторы должны быть округлены - `round` до нужной ширины.

```css
li {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.small {
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 15px 0 0;
  border-image:url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4127/border.png") 27 27 round;
}

.large {
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 30px 0 0;
  border-image:url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4127/border.png") 27 27 round;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="small">First list item</li>
  <li class="large">Second list item</li>
</ul>
```

Я здесь использовал ромбики в формате PNG с сайта MDN , но вы можете достаточно легко создать PNG-файл (или SVG) с желаемой формой точки.

На вопрос ответил  - **Paul LeBeau**